# Readable SQL queries when filtering date + time stamp on today

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

When filtering on rows from today and if I want Oracle to use an index I would avoid the truncate function. I would write

```
trade_date >= trunc(sysdate) and trade_date < trunc(sysdate+1)
```

instead of

```
trunc(trade_date) = trunc(sysdate)
```

But the later is much more readable.

Is there a trick to gain readability and still use the index? I'm looking for a general solution to be used in several SQLs (so no Function-Based Indexes)

Comment: Depends how you define readability - the first one looks fine to me, but maybe I've been doing this too long... What would make it better, having variables for 'today' and 'tomorrow' to hide the trunc and addition? Or are you hoping to use equality? Or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: I am afraid that especially the trade_date < trunc(sysdate+1) is hard to read and understand. Also another developer may in the future re-write it to the form trunc(trade_date) = trunc(sysdate) thinking he did a great job. :)

Comment: The first one looks fine to me too, I don't see a better way. Remember that if you are often accessing by trunc(trade_date) you should consider creating a Function Based index like: CREATE INDEX trade_date_idx ON table (TRUNC(trade_date));

Comment: Or `trade_date between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate+1)`, or even just `trade_date = sysdate`, both of which might also look reasonable to someone who doesn't know why the trunc option is wrong; but aren't the same at all. Aside from adding comments to say why it's done, which you don't really want to have to do throughout your code, not much you can do about that really. Hope code review catches it?

Comment: You could add an extra column with just the date and rename the current column to trade_datetime or something. Although anything I can think of can (and will) someday be abused by an ignorant developer.

Comment: Rather than adding an extra column with just the date, you could add a virtual column instead, and have that set to `trunc(trade_date)`, then you could index that. But you'd have to remember to use that column in the queries in order to use the index. Personally, I'd stick with the original query and if I were that concerned about future developers, I'd add a comment in the code explaining my decision.

Comment: Hi and thanks for all you suggestions. I was looking for a solution that would work without changing definition. I will continue using the 1st form.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, there is nothing called `more readable` if you want better performance. Any intermediate developer would read both in similar manner. So forget about readability.

Best way is to create 2 similar tables and put few thousand records and use both ways to compare the cost.

I tried using one of my table with few million records and compared both. Although the cost is almost same for both , `trunc(trade_date) = trunc(sysdate)` performed better than `trade_date BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate+1)` upon multiple trials on multiple columns on different connections.

So I would suggest second method for indexing too. Although I didn't create index on them, but you can try and check for yourself.

Comment: 1st priority is to hit the index, next I would like it to readable.

Comment: Why the downvote? I compared both scenarios with few million records to compare performance of both conditions and came up with `trunc(trade_date) = trunc(sysdate)` is better while using in `where` condition. What else you were expecting that you downvoted it?

Comment: Okay maybe I misunderstood you. However, it seems like you are testing the two scenarios without an index. There should be a huge different if the first hits the index and the seconds does not.

Comment: I didn't check the scenarios for index. I compared them in `where` clause for few million rows to compare which works better.

Comment: Okay, the question was about still hitting the index with a readable query.